# Mage::getStoreconfig() from a cron script

Tags: php, magento

I've seen this issue before, just wondered if anyone is aware of it. And what's the best strategy to tackle it.
The problem:

`Mage::getStoreconfig($path)` without second parameter (store id) returns config for a current store. When used in cron script, it seems Current Store wasn't instantiated properly, that's why this funciton returns null instead of correct value.

Is there a way to make it use "Default store" (admin store) - or maybe init the current store before the call?

**UPDATE**

I've added `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);` line in order to set current store, but inside cron execution my script still doesn't see the result after calling `Mage::getStoreConfig('...');`.

I've checked - the value is set correctly in the admin panel (and in db).

**UPDATE 2**

I've checked the whole code one more time, and it seems it's working fine now. Anyway the answer below is the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set Admin store

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);
```

To set other store, replace 0 with store id.

Comment: Hi @Krishna - actually I was too quick in my acceptance. I've added that line to set current store, and I had it working through shell script, but cron on production actually still doesn't see `Mage::getStoreConfig` result. I'll keep your answer as the correct answer, but I'll update the thread later when I find the reason

Comment: I just checked the code one more time, and it seems to work now. Thanks for your answer again.